# how to create a knockout hint text custom binding?

Tags: knockout.js, ko-custom-binding

Im trying to create a custom binding to show hint texts in text inputs.

so far I have this but it doesnt work:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.hintText= {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        element.focus(function () {
            if ($(this).val() === defaultText) {
                $(this).attr("value", "");
            }
        });
        element.blur(function () {
            if ($(this).val() === '') {
                $(this).val(valueAccessor());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

the html:

```
<input id="profileID" type="text" data-bind="hintText:'Enter Profile ID'" />
```

Comment: do you mean like the HTML `placeholder` attribute?

Comment: yes, like that, but I want to create a custom binding instead of using the place holder.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/12636695/866172

Comment: would the built-in `attr: {placeholder: myHintText}` binding work for you?

Comment: does that work in IE and all other browsers?

Comment: Another similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934023/text-input-watermark-using-custom-bindinghandler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HTML5 `placeholder` attribute should accomplish this for you.

If your browser requirements support the `placeholder` attribute, you can call it directly using the KnockOutJS' `attr` binding like this:

```
<input data-bind="attr:{placeholder: hintText}">
```

If you need support for older browser, there is a shim that should work for you:  https://github.com/parndt/jquery-html5-placeholder-shim

In order to use this shim, you'd need to create custom binding so that you can manually call `$.placeholder.shim();` as necessary when the placeholder changes.

Here's a "placeholder" binding that applies the shim (**edited**):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.placeholder = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var placeholderValue = valueAccessor();
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { attr: { placeholder: placeholderValue} } );
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor){
        $.placeholder.shim();
    }
};
```

Your html would then look like this:

```
<input data-bind="placeholder: hintText">
```